# SessionFactory opensession throwing a nullpointerexception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I've been practicing on Hibernate and MySQL for the past few days and I've ran into this error showing that I have a NullPointerException on my sessionFactory variable in setUpSession.java running the program as a JUnit test.

My current goal right now is to establish a connection between my program and the database. The connection doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Have I configured the schema or database wrongly in the first place? Or have I misunderstood the tutorials I've read and used the wrong the code?

SetUpSession.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SetUpSession extends TestCase{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//  @Override
//  protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
//      if(sessionFactory != null) {
//          sessionFactory.close();
//      }
//  }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public void testBasicUsage() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List result = session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
        for(Employee employee : (List<Employee>) result) {
            System.out.println( employee.getId() + " " + employee.getFirstName() );
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.gmail.predicatablebeaco.HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false)
    private String type;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String password, String phone, String address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory_schema</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">predi</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.gmail.predicatablebeaco.HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample.Employee" />


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.gmail.predicatablebeaco</groupId>
  <artifactId>HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my current workspace in eclipse right now:

[Workspace image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5pBy.jpg)

Errors detected:

```
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.3.Final}
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory_schema]
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=predi, password=****}
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Wed Aug 14 21:34:53 GMT+08:00 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : null
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:54 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:54 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Could not create connection to database server.
Aug 14, 2019 9:34:54 PM org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl stopService
INFO: HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:389)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:340)
    at com.gmail.predicatablebeaco.HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample.SetUpSession.setUp(SetUpSession.java:25)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:180)
    at com.gmail.predicatablebeaco.HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample.SetUpSession.setUp(SetUpSession.java:22)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1863)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    ... 52 more
org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources@73d983ea
```

Failure Trace

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.config.spi.ConfigurationService]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:624)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:180)
    at com.gmail.predicatablebeaco.HibernatePersistenceAnnotationsExample.SetUpSession.testBasicUsage(SetUpSession.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code snippet:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.List;
public class HbConnectionTest {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the additional edit. I put it in wrong place. I've tested the code you put up. I have a UnknownServiceException in my Failure Trace and a org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException in my console.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things that I don't think matter, but check. If you are using anything newer MySQL 5 or newer you should be using a different dialect.

### Driver and dialect **(probably not the issue)**

The latest Hibernate 5.4 distribution as of 6/6/2020 includes the following MySQL dialects:

- MySQL55Dialect
- MySQL57Dialect
- MySQL57InnoDBDialect
- MySQL5Dialect
- MySQL8Dialect
- MySQLDialect
- MySQLInnoDBDialect
- MySQLISAMDialect

MySQL also prefers this driver:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

### This missing addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class)

My hunch is you haven't added the Employee to the MetadataSources before building the registry. I use this code in a [SessionFactory example](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/3-ways-to-build-a-Hibernate-SessionFactory-in-Java-by-example) in my Hibernate book. I've commented out the addAnnotatedClass(Player.class) call. You'll need to uncomment this and replace Player.class with your Employee class and whatever JPA annotated objects you have in your problem domain.

```
MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry);
// metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(Player.class);
Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();

// here we build the SessionFactory (Hibernate 5.4)
SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

### Simple Configuration

By the way, I like the use of the Metadata, but if all else fails, you could always give this alternate approach to [Hibernate SessionFactory creation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fo11opVImo8) a try:

```
// SessionFactory in Hibernate 5 example
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.configure();
// local SessionFactory bean created
SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
return session;
```